# Missing property direction in Azure HTTP functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

newbie here to code and especially with Azure. I hit a rock with bellow placed Azure functions code. When I press F5 to load it goes to an error saying "`Missing property direction`"

I'm wondering whether this is a missing extension error or something else, the code is from the video course and the tutor still has not responded to the message, if anyone can help?
P.S. there are two function files with the same error:

processOrderCosmos,
processOrderStorage

[image]

Comment: Can I access the code anywhere?

Comment: `"direction": "in",` try adding this to your bindings section. Also you need to update to latest versions of the nuget packages as you can see in the warnings.

Comment: If you are using c# script, for your function, then refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger#example) for knowing more about function.json entries.

Answer (score -1):

If the **Azure Functions** is on **C# Class Library**, the `direction` property will not be defined in `function.json`.

In fact, it will get direction according to the `.dll` file generated when you compiled the Azure Function.

As [Anand Sowmithiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14973743/anand-sowmithiran) said, `direction:in` is required in `function.json` when you use trigger in the declaration part of the C# Azure Function.

This **`function.json`** file will be in debug or release folder of the Azure Functions Solution.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp-script%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example) for more information on [`function.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp#binding-direction) entries and keep the track of this similar issue recorded in [GitHub Issues Repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/272) which is in open state.